# Is it possible to code in jQuery in a JS file? (.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

Is it possible to code using jQuery in a JS file? (.**js**) if so, can you please tell me?

Comment: jQuery is a Javascript library, my friend. So yes, it is possible. In fact this is the default way

Comment: what exactly you want to do ? please clear you question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option -1:

Download the jquery file and store it in the directory of the project and add the script tag in your html file and then add second js file which you can write jquery

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>  //Here you can write your custom js with jquery loaded first
```

Option -2 :

First take the script file you want to add jquery into and add the following lines of code

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

To test whether jquery actually loaded write this function in main.js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("Hello Jquery loaded in js file");
});
```

Suppose you are using main.js file then write the above 2 code snippets to implement and use the jquery  in js file.

Comment: where can I download jQuery?

Comment: No need to download include the code snippets into your main.js file

Comment: I did but don't have enough rep. to make it show, @SaiKiranUppu . if you can upvoting my question will me reach 15 rep.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to reference `jquery.js` in `<script>` tag of your `html` file before your your other `js` files

jQuery: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js

Comment: do I download jQuery?

Comment: you may, be you don't have to. you can reference remote source like https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js

Answer (score 0):

create an external .js file and include it in your html page.Like your are loading jquery.min.js,you load your created .js file and write your jquery code in it and it works.
You can check it by a simple code  in your js file

```
$(document).load(function(){
alert("Jquery loaded and js file working");
});
```

If you are getting alet dialogbox saying the above , that means your jquery and .js file loaded successfully and working fine.You can write all your jquery code in that file.

Answer (score -1):

## **Option 1:**

To use jQuery in js files use the following code: (HTML)

jsfiddle example: ow.ly/LTS13043ny2

#### **NOTE:** You must include the jQuery  ***BEFORE*** the main js file, in this case, `script.js`

---

## Option 2:

To use jQuery in js file use the following code: (Javascript)

jsfiddle example:  ow.ly/hzi33043noG

#### **NOTE:** You must have 2 files, `load.js` (as show bellow), and script.js (your main code)

---

## Option 3:

Copy and paste all the code from [this url](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js) into your main script file.
You can now use jQuery.

jsfiddle example ow.ly/SJ1u3043nHo

---

If code isn't running comment below the error.